Detecting OR operator sequences and wrapping their content in a parenthesis when building a query with PHP
I made the following PHP code to build a query based on user input, where they can choose the condition and the operator and the resulting query would be printed on their screen every time they added something to the query:
if (!isset($_SESSION['filter_'.$c])) { // if its the first filter inserted
    if ($operator == "NOT") {
        @$_SESSION['query_first_'.$c] = "NOT $selected_condition";
    } else {
        @$_SESSION['query_first_'.$c] = "$selected_condition";
    }
}

if ($operator == "OR" || $operator == 'OR NOT' || $operator == 'AND' || $operator == 'AND NOT') {
    @$current_filter = "$operator $selected_condition";
    @$_SESSION['query_'.$c] = " " . @$_SESSION['query_'.$c] . @$current_filter;
}

@$write_first = $_SESSION['query_first_'.$c];
@$write_last = $_SESSION['query_'.$c];

$_SESSION['filter_'.$c] = @$write_first . @$write_last;

This is in a function that is called whenever the user adds another condition, keeping the session variables between calls.
the output would be something like
WHERE condition AND condition OR NOT condition AND condition OR condition OR condition
So, I wanted to add parenthesis around the OR parts.
WHERE condition AND (condition OR NOT condition) AND (condition OR condition OR condition)
The latest solution I thought of would've been encasing all of the occurences in parenthesis at the end, then when the function gets called, it would remove all parenthesis so it wouldn't have duplicates.
With my limited knowledge of Regex, I only managed to come up with this:
(?<=(AND\s)(NOT\s)*).+(?:OR\s+).+(?=\s+AND)
This doesn't really work, the main issues being the 0 or more operator in that NOT making the search ignore it, and the fact that this can only detect a single segment.
I tried another solution as well, which would open the parenthesis when the user input used an OR operator and close it when it went back to AND. I hit a roadblock when it got to the regex as well, and I don't have the code anymore.
I tried looking up solutions to those specific tiny Regex issues but I didn't know what to look for, or how. The results I found weren't great.

I would suggest first finding a way to visualize the groups for the user. It's hard to tell how the user wants them grouped with a straight query/array. If you can visualize it for the user, it would allow you to put the groupings into array to better create the query.

Although not related to your problem, using error suppression as much as you are is a giant code smell for me.

To insert the parenthesis without a fixed syntax and have infinite AND and OR statements
would it not be as simple as splitting your if statement: like this
i tried the sql code and it would run fine
yours:
if ($operator == "OR" || $operator == 'OR NOT' || $operator == 'AND' || $operator == 'AND NOT') {
    @$current_filter = "$operator $selected_condition";
    @$_SESSION['query_'.$c] = " ".@$_SESSION['query_'.$c].@$current_filter;
}

and split up
 // splitup:
 $opened = false;// outside of the loop(global variable) 
// loop : 
@$current_filter = "";

if ($operator == "OR" || $operator == 'OR NOT') { // only add a open if its the first OR encountered 
  if(!$opened){
    @$current_filter += "( " ; $opened = true;}
    @$current_filter += $selected_condition." ".$operator." ";
    
}
else if ($operator == 'AND' || $operator == 'AND NOT') { // close the parentesis when a AND is encounterd
  if($opened){
    @$current_filter += $selected_condition.") ".$operator." ";
    $opened = false;
  }else{
    @$current_filter += $selected_condition." ".$operator." ";
  }
else {  // do if no more operators
  $Fullstring += $selected_condition;
  if($opened){
    $Fullstring += ")";
     $opened = false;
  }
}
@$_SESSION['query_'.$c] = " " . @$_SESSION['query_'.$c] . @$current_filter;

result split up in the different loops of the if statements , probably can make a SWITCH out of it :
so WHERE

condition AND
(condition OR NOT
condition )AND
( condition OR
condition OR
condition)

or WHERE

condition AND
( condition OR NOT
condition ) AND
( condition OR
condition ) AND
condition

its still posible

yeah, I feel pretty stupid now. Thanks.
Though I'll split the not from the or/and because with your solution, it isn't possible for the user to set "NOT" for the first condition.
